# Split one column by every into "n" columns with one character each

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with one single column and 10 rows. Every column has the same number of characters (5). From this file I would like to get a file with 10 rows and 5 columns, where each column has 1 character only. I have no idea on how to do that in linux.. Any help? Would AWK do this?

The real data has many more rows (>4K) and characters (>500K) though. Here is a short version of the real data:

```
31313
30442
11020
12324
00140
34223
34221
43124
12211
04312
```

Desired output:

```
3 1 3 1 3
3 0 4 4 2
1 1 0 2 0
1 2 3 2 4
0 0 1 4 0
3 4 2 2 3
3 4 2 2 1
4 3 1 2 4
1 2 2 1 1
0 4 3 1 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] your question to show us what the output would look like, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed` as well:

```
sed 's/./& /g; s/ $//' file

3 1 3 1 3
3 0 4 4 2
1 1 0 2 0
1 2 3 2 4
0 0 1 4 0
3 4 2 2 3
3 4 2 2 1
4 3 1 2 4
1 2 2 1 1
0 4 3 1 2
```

Comment: with GNU sed, you can do `sed 's/./ &/2g'`

Answer (score 3):

I think that this does what you want:

```
$ awk -F '' '{ $1 = $1 }1' file
3 1 3 1 3
3 0 4 4 2
1 1 0 2 0
1 2 3 2 4
0 0 1 4 0
3 4 2 2 3
3 4 2 2 1
4 3 1 2 4
1 2 2 1 1
0 4 3 1 2
```

The input field separator is set to the empty string, so every character is treated as a field. `$1 = $1` means that awk "touches" every record, causing it to be reformatted, inserting the output field separator (a space) between every character. `1` is the shortest "true" condition, causing awk to print every record.

Note that the behaviour of setting the field separator to an empty string isn't well-defined, so may not work on your version of awk. You may find that setting the field separator differently e.g. by using `-v FS=` works for you.

Alternatively, you can do more or less the same thing in Perl:

```
perl -F -lanE 'say "@F"' file
```

`-a` splits each input record into the special array `@F`. `-F` followed by nothing sets the input field separator to the empty string. The quotes around `@F` mean that the list separator (a space by default) is inserted between each element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but  received the following message: "awk: field separator FS is empty". So, I googled about that and I changed your code to "awk -v FS= '{ $1 = $1 }1' file" and it worked!!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this isn't trivial to do with most standard Unix tools (update: [except, apparently, with `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38398978/1126841)). I would use Python:

```
python -c 'import sys; map(sys.stdout.write, map(" ".join, sys.stdin))' in.txt > new.txt
```

(This isn't the greatest idiomatic Python, but it suffices for a simple one-liner.)

Answer (score 0):

another unix toolchain for this task

```
$ while read line; do echo $line | fold -w1 | xargs; done < file

3 1 3 1 3
3 0 4 4 2
1 1 0 2 0
1 2 3 2 4
0 0 1 4 0
3 4 2 2 3
3 4 2 2 1
4 3 1 2 4
1 2 2 1 1
0 4 3 1 2
```